# Mapping data from nested JSON files

Tags: json

I'm trying to use a map function to pass all of the country names for a given continent into React components. I think I might need to convert this to an array, but I don't know how I would access the `name` key for each object given the objects all have different names.

```
  "AD": {
    "name": "Andorra",
    "native": "Andorra",
    "phone": "376",
    "continent": "EU",
    "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "languages": [
      "ca"
    ]
  },
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    "phone": "971",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
    "currency": "AED",
    "languages": [
      "ar"
    ]
  },
  "AF": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "native": "افغانستان",
    "phone": "93",
    "continent": "AS",
    "capital": "Kabul",
    "currency": "AFN",
    "languages": [
      "ps",
      "uz",
      "tk"
    ]
  },
  "AG": {
    "name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "native": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "phone": "1268",
    "continent": "NA",
    "capital": "Saint John's",
    "currency": "XCD",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  },
  "AI": {
    "name": "Anguilla",
    "native": "Anguilla",
    "phone": "1264",
    "continent": "NA",
    "capital": "The Valley",
    "currency": "XCD",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
var countryNames = [];
for(let key in YourJsonData){
    countryNames.push(YourJsonData[key][name]);
}
```

then loop over that array and render the elements in your component